# Azure AD SAML certificate Base64 vs X509Certificate

Tags: azure, active-directory, base64, saml, x509certificate

For Enterprise applications SSO with SAML, we have the following options for the SAML certificate.
[SAML certificates]https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRqkS.png

Is there any difference between the Base64 encoded certificate and the X509Certificate format within the Federation Metadata XML?

In the past, I believed they were the same and encountered no issues with using base64 format with the applications.  However, recently I have encountered problems with base64 format and noticed that the two files contained different certificates. As a workaround, I used the X509Certificate format instead of the Base64 encoded format to ensure the application functions correctly. I would like to confirm if they are supposed to be different. If anyone has insights on this matter, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

The format of X.509 certificates in SAML metadata is a base-64 string. It should be the same as the base-64 certificate file that you can download separately from Azure. All three formats should produce exactly the same certificate.

Comment: Thank you. That was my understanding as well. Unfortunately, this has not been my experience recently. The base64 and x509 in metadata are showing different values.